# $ \displaystyle \sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C},~ \vert\lambda \vert \leq M_{x}} \sup_{n} \vert x_{n}+\lambda \vert=2M_{x}$.

Tags: calculus

Let $ x=(x_{n})_{n} $ be a bounded complex sequence and let
$ M_{x}= \displaystyle \sup_{n} \vert x_{n}\vert $.
 Prove that
 $$  \sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C},~ \vert\lambda \vert \leq M_{x}} \sup_{n} \vert x_{n}+\lambda \vert=2M_{x}.$$

I used the fact that  the disk  of center the origin $O$ and radius=$M_{x} $ is compact, but the set of the elements of thesequence  $ x=(x_{n})_{n} $ may be no closed.

Any kind of help is thanked in advabced!

Answer (score 1):

First, for any $n$ and any $\lambda$ in the disk of center $0$ and radius $M_x$, we have that $|x_n+\lambda | \leq |x_n| + |\lambda | \leq M_x + M_x = 2M_x$. Taking the $\sup$ first over $n$, then over $\lambda$, we get the inequality $\sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C},~ \vert\lambda \vert \leq M_{x}} \sup_{n} \vert x_{n}+\lambda \vert \leq 2M_{x}$.

For the other way, let us fix $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $n$ such that $M_x - |x_n|\leq \epsilon$. Let us write $x_n=|x_n| e^{i\theta }$, where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us set $\lambda = M_xe^{i\theta }$. Then, we have $|x_n+\lambda|=|x_n|+M_x \geq 2M_x - \epsilon$. We can take the $\sup$ first over $n$, then over $\lambda$, and we get that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C},~ \vert\lambda \vert \leq M_{x}} \sup_{n} \vert x_{n}+\lambda \vert \geq 2M_{x}-\epsilon$.

It follows that $\sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C},~ \vert\lambda \vert \leq M_{x}} \sup_{n} \vert x_{n}+\lambda \vert \geq 2M_{x}$, and hence we obtain the desired equality.

Comment: With a slight modification, the result is also true if we impose $\lambda < M_x$. One would just have to consider $\lambda = (M_x - \epsilon)e^{i\theta }$ instead, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.